# Stop print driver from opening windows

Tags: windows, drivers, printing, c#, windows-server-2012-r2

A program I've written is being used to send shipping labels to a label printer - or, more precisely, to five printers, each on a separate driver I've set up. The throughput is one every three seconds for each printer, so there's a lot of windows popping up that say "Printing - Page 1 of document" - sometimes for all five printers at once - and we're planning to extend the program to 10 printers. Is there any way get the drivers configured to not show this window? The program and drivers are on a computer running Windows Server 2012 R2. The driver is for InterMec px4i printers, and I'm using System.Drawing.Printing under C# .NET 4.0.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/robgy.jpg]

Comment: You may want to try various applications on  your system with a different print driver to see if it's the API you're using to submit the print (what language? what API? you didn't specify, so it's impossible to help you further) or if it's the driver itself. If it's the driver itself, the method to make the driver not display the popup would be entirely driver-specific; you may have to take drastic measures to suppress them, like hooking a DLL or something. Other drivers might be *configurable* and have a setting to disable the popup.

Comment: To clarify, the driver is for InterMec px4i printers, and I'm using System.Drawing.Printing under C# .NET 4.0.

Comment: Why did you remove the image from the post after I put it in for you?

Comment: It gave me the notification, when I edited it, that I needed at least 10 reputation points to post images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it is the default print controller itself that causes the window to appear. System.Drawing.Printing gives all new PrintDocuments the default print controller. When setting up the page to print, my program goes through the following statements:

```
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = PrinterName;
    ...
```

What I did to solve the problem was to give it a new print controller using the default constructor:

```
    pd.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
```

Now there are no "Printing..." windows popping up, and this has also visibly increased the performance of my program. I hope this helps anyone else having this problem, but it should probably be moved to StackOverflow as it is a programming problem, not a windows problem.